# Touch id taking some time to verify

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using the following routine to get the touch id to work I know touch id will only tell me they are the owner of the device but what I want to know is why is it taking five seconds to return to the UI. I get the success OK so I no my code is working ok but I don't no why its taking five seconds.

Also with touch id only ever returning a true or false should we really relies on it. I was going ask for touch after they enter their usual email and password or should I store this in iPhone key chain I'm not to sure what the best practice is here.

```
- (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender {
    LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error]) {
        [context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
                localizedReason:@"Are you the device owner?"
                          reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

                              if (error) {
                                  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                  message:@"There was a problem verifying your identity."
                                                                                 delegate:nil
                                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                  [alert show];
                                  return;
                              }

                              if (success) {
                                  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success"
                                                                                  message:@"You are the device owner!"
                                                                                 delegate:nil
                                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                  [alert show];

                              } else {
                                  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                  message:@"You are not the device owner."
                                                                                 delegate:nil
                                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                  [alert show];
                              }

                          }];

    } else {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Your device cannot authenticate using TouchID."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to dispatch back to the main thread from the completion handler to update the ui (display an alert)

Comment: @Paulw11 can you provide an example and ill mark as answer thanks just learning objective c

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks i got it wth 
                                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{    [alert show]; });